# Finding duplicate Li element in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code below...

```
var duplicate = $("ul li").map(function(){return $(this).attr("menutitle")}).get();
```

If i output `duplicate` in console

```
console.log(duplicate);
```

Iam getting below values:

> ["Products", "title", "Recruitment", "My", "Just"]

but the actual values are

> ["Products", "title", "Recruitment", "My Menu", "Just Time"]

so its ignoring the elements after `space`..

How can I fix this issue?

Secondly Iam trying to check duplicate values...

```
console.log($.inArray('products', duplicate));
```

it is loging as `-1` ideally it should log `1 or 0` right ?if the value matches?

if i use

```
console.log($.inArray('Products', duplicate));
```

So it is case sensitive, how to make this case insensitive?

Comment: Show your code or set the fiddle.

Comment: try this once http://jsfiddle.net/qy3ZQ/

Comment: @Ram Iam trying your answer now...

Comment: _“so its ignoring the elements after space”_ – did you forget to put quotes around the attribute values in your HTML …?

Comment: @Ram tried .. its not working.... its giving True for both ,`ducts ` and `products` ... first case remains the same... Its not taking value after `space` ....@CBroe quote seems to be fine.. no problem...

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/qy3ZQ/3/

Comment: Hi @Ram thanks alot for trying.. but now its displaying only 'false' for any values